# How do we register a function in Spark-Scala and Cataloging UDF among the other functions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am new in Spark with Scala, I was following the code snippet given below and my question is when I should register a function like this for what purpose and why we do cataloging user defined function among the other functions like this? Where it is used? I cannot understand the output I have given below which is coming.
I will be thankful to anyone from my heart if anyone tell me. with regards.

```
scala> spark.udf.register("myUpper", (input:String) => input.toUpperCase)
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> spark.catalog.listFunctions.filter('name like "%upper%").show(false)
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+
|name |database|description|className                                      |isTemporary|
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+
|upper|null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Upper|true       |
+-----+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For usage in SQL:

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT myUpper('foo')").show
+----------------+
|UDF:myUpper(foo)|
+----------------+
|             FOO|
+----------------+
```

`selectExpr`:

```
scala> spark.range(0, 1).selectExpr("myUpper('foo')").show
+----------------+
|UDF:myUpper(foo)|
+----------------+
|             FOO|
+----------------+
```

`org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr`

```
scala> spark.range(0, 1).select(expr("myUpper('foo')")).show
+----------------+
|UDF:myUpper(foo)|
+----------------+
|             FOO|
+----------------+
```

and expression filters:

```
scala> spark.range(0, 1).where("myUpper('foo') = 'FOO'").show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

spark maintains a `dataset` of `functions` (inbuilt) which can be used without registering.

```
scala> spark.catalog.listFunctions
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.catalog.Function] = [name: string, database: string ... 3 more fields]
```

Now before we register a function

```
scala> spark.catalog.listFunctions.filter('name like "%pper%").show
+-----+--------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
| name|database|description|           className|isTemporary|
+-----+--------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
|upper|    null|       null|org.apache.spark....|       true|
+-----+--------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
```

After we register

```
scala> spark.udf.register("myUpper", (input:String) => input.toUpperCase)
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> spark.catalog.listFunctions.filter('name like "%pper%").show
+-------+--------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
|   name|database|description|           className|isTemporary|
+-------+--------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
|myUpper|    null|       null|                null|       true|
|  upper|    null|       null|org.apache.spark....|       true|
+-------+--------+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
```

Now we can use `myUpper` function as we use other functions

```
scala> spark.catalog.listFunctions.show(50, false)
+---------------------+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|name                 |database|description|className                                                              |isTemporary|
+---------------------+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|!                    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Not                          |true       |
|%                    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Remainder                    |true       |
|&                    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BitwiseAnd                   |true       |
|*                    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Multiply                     |true       |
|+                    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Add                          |true       |
|-                    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Subtract                     |true       |
.................................................................
...................................................................
|==                   |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.EqualTo                      |true       |
|>                    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GreaterThan                  |true       |
|>=                   |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GreaterThanOrEqual           |true       |
|^                    |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BitwiseXor                   |true       |
|abs                  |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Abs                          |true       |
|acos                 |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Acos                         |true       |
|add_months           |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AddMonths                    |true       |
|and                  |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.And                          |true       |
|approx_count_distinct|null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.HyperLogLogPlusPlus|true       |
|array                |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.CreateArray                  |true       |
|array_contains       |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ArrayContains                |true       |
|ascii                |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Ascii                        |true       |
|asin                 |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Asin                         |true       |
.....................................................
.....................................................
.........................................................
|assert_true          |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AssertTrue                   |true       
|covar_pop            |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.CovPopulation      |true       |
|covar_samp           |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate.CovSample          |true       |
|crc32                |null    |null       |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Crc32                        |true       |
+---------------------+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

There are plenty of functions.

These functions can be used with `withColumn`, `select`, `aggregations` etc.

I hope the answer is helpful